# Pydantic created at and updated at fields

Tags: python, database, postgresql, fastapi, pydantic

I'm new to using Pydantic and I'm using it to set up the models for FastAPI to integrate with my postgres database. I want to make a model that has an updated_at and created_at field which store the last datetime the model was updated and the datetime the model was created. I figured created_at could be something like this:

```
created_at: datetime = datetime.now()
```

How would I do an updated_at so it updates the datetime automatically every time the model is updated?

Comment: In your model set updated_at to None using optional then go where you wrote you update logic(your update route) and set update_at to datetime.now when the user request a update and it success.

Comment: How are you integrating with your Postgres database? This is probably better handled on the database access layer than on the Pydantic layer.

Comment: @MatsLindh Could you elaborate a bit more on this or share some documentation?

Comment: @bballboy8 For anyone to be able to say how you do that or share some documentation, they'll need to know _what you use to talk to your postgres database_. Are you using SQLAlchemy? psychopg2 or asyncpg directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a validator which will update the field `updated_at` each time when some other data in the model will change. The [root_validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators) and the [validate_assignment](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customization) config attribute are what you are looking for.

This is the sample code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

from pydantic import BaseModel,root_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    data: str = "Some data"
    created_at: datetime = datetime.now()
    updated_at: datetime = datetime.now()

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True

    @root_validator
    def number_validator(cls, values):
        values["updated_at"] = datetime.now()
        return values


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar = Foo()
    print(bar.dict())
    sleep(5)
    bar.data = "New data"
    print(bar.dict())
```

and the output:

```
{
 'data': 'Some data',
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 10, 41, 13, 176243),
 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 10, 41, 13, 179253)
}

{
 'data': 'New data',
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 10, 41, 13, 176243),
 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 10, 41, 18, 184983)
}
```

You can see that there is a difference in microseconds after object creation. If this is a problem you can set: 
 `updated_at: Optional[datetime] = None` 
and modify the validator like this:

```
    @root_validator
    def number_validator(cls, values):
        if values["updated_at"]:
            values["updated_at"] = datetime.now()
        else:
            values["updated_at"] = values["created_at"]
        return values
```

and the new output:

```
{
 'data': 'Some data',
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 10, 54, 33, 715379), 
 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 10, 54, 33, 715379)
}

{
 'data': 'New data',
 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 10, 54, 33, 715379),
 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 10, 54, 38, 728778)
}
```

Comment: `Parameter 'skip_on_failure' unfilled 
Pydantic V1 style `@root_validator` validators are deprecated. You should migrate to Pydantic V2 style `@model_validator` validators, see the migration guide for more details `

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has some depracated syntaxes.

I found the following solution compatible with PyDantic V2.

```py
# Standard library imports
from datetime import datetime

# Third party imports
from pydantic import Field, model_validator, ConfigDict

NOW_FACTORY = datetime.now


class CreatedUpdatedAt:
    """Created and updated at mixin that automatically updates updated_at field."""

    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=NOW_FACTORY)
    updated_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=NOW_FACTORY)

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        validate_assignment=True,
    )

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    @classmethod
    def update_updated_at(cls, obj: "CreatedUpdatedAt") -> "CreatedUpdatedAt":
        """Update updated_at field."""
        # must disable validation to avoid infinite loop
        obj.model_config["validate_assignment"] = False

        # update updated_at field
        obj.updated_at = NOW_FACTORY()

        # enable validation again
        obj.model_config["validate_assignment"] = True
        return obj
```

Then you should be able to use this mixin to inherit your models that will automatically update the updated_at field on a value assignment.

```py
class Foo(CreatedUpdatedAt, BaseModel):
    """Example model."""

    bar: str

foo = Foo(bar="foobar")

print(foo.updated_at)

time.sleep(5)

print(foo.updated_at) # should have the latest timestamp
```